# Вопрос по Джанге, аутентификация

Tags: django

Пользователь авторизовался, но через примерно 15 минут он должен заново проходить авторизацию, как сделать так что бы увеличить продолжительность на 2 3 часов

Comment: Не должен. Время жизни авторизационной куки по умолчанию две недели. Если у вас меньше, смотрите настройки или ищите ошибки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а где смотреть настройки, в браузере?

Comment: В проекте, в web-сервере и в браузере. Диагностика проблем - неотъемлемая часть работы программиста.